# Mysql Query maching exactly id(s) array

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on a exactly condition.

For example my table is

```
genre_id  series_id
1         1
1         2
2         5
4         1
2         4
3         3
```

I want to get `genre_id` which contain exactly `series_id` **1**.

So my query will return only `genre_id` **4** not `genre_id` **1**

But this query

```
SELECT genre_id FROM test
WHERE genre_id IN (1)
GROUP BY series_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

returns `genre_id` **1** and **2**

Comment: post your table (SHOW CREATE and not a screenshot) along with the rows of data in question

Comment: Why do you select series_id if you are looking for genre_id? The question is hard to understand anyway, but as your code and your description are diverging, it's starting to become ambiguous.

Comment: I edited the SQL query, yes I want to return genre_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
drop table t;
create table t (genre_id int, series_id int);
insert into t values
(1,         1),
(1,         2),
(2,         5),
(4,         1),
(2,         4),
(3,         3);
*/

select  s.genre_id
from
(
select   genre_id , max(series_id) maxsid
from        t
group       by genre_id
) s
where   s.maxsid = 1;
```

result

```
+----------+
| genre_id |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
```

Comment: This is too specific. I.e, not scalable.

Comment: @strawberry - thanks ,not sure I understand what you mean by that - is there a way you can share your thinking with me on this site?.

Comment: Well, what if the OP wanted 'exactly series ids 1 & 2' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.genre_id
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.genre_id = x.genre_id 
   AND y.series_id NOT IN(1) 
 WHERE y.genre_id IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY x.genre_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are using wrong query:

```
SELECT series_id FROM test WHERE genre_id IN (1) GROUP BY series_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Use

```
SELECT genre_id FROM test WHERE  series_id IN (1) GROUP BY genre_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```